# serializeArray cannot find some inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html structure :

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Mini description (affichage dernières destinations ajoutées et meta description)</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
        <div class="metadata">
          <label>Titre de la page</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text"></input>
          <label>Titre meta</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="meta-title" type="text"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I submit the data I do this :

```
console.log($("#meta-keyword").length);
var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
console.log(unindexed_array);
```

The first console log shows 1, but I cannot find my input in `unindexed_array`.

However, I find my input with the id `description`.

Have any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have `name` on some inputs

Without a `name` they can't be submitted in a form and therefore won't be serialized by `serialize()` or `serlizeArray()`

`name` is what is used as the `key` for key/value pair

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<form>` tag in your HTML, to serialize!

Comment: Are you sure, there will be need of `<form>` to use serialize ? The name attribute for every input is required. There is not need to have  `<form>`